# Is there a way to combine two 2D arrays using a stored key?

Tags: python-3.x

I'm writing a python script to read in a netCDF file in Ugrid format. This requires reading in two 2D arrays:

```
x_coordinate  = [[0,0],[1,200],[2,400],[3,600],[4,800]...]   
y_coordinate  = [[0,0],[1,5],[2,10],[3,15],[4,20]...]
```

and outputting an array:

```
coordinates = [[0,0],[200,5],[400,10],[600,15],[800,20]...]
```

so that I can then display it through mpl. Is there a way to do this efficiently without iterating through with comparative if statements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion, `zip()` with list comprehension should solve your problem. 
Example as follows:

```
>>>list(zip([el[1] for el in y_coordinate], [el[1] for el in x_coordinate]))
[(0, 0), (5, 200), (10, 400), (15, 600), (20, 800)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try:

```
[[x[0][1], x[1][1]] for x in zip(x_coordinate, y_coordinate)]
```